# Template arguments to template functions

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I just released a skiplist container library. And the Sun compiler complains about this:

```
template <class T, class R>
bool operator==(const IndexedSkipList<T,R> &left, const IndexedSkipList<T,R> &right)
{
  return ((left.size() == right.size()) &&
          (std::equal(left.begin(), left.end(), right.begin())));
}
```

The errors are:

```
"include/CSIndexedSkipList.h", line 65: Error: Too few arguments for template std::reverse_iterator<CS::BidiIdxIterator<CS::IndexedSkipList<CS::T, CS::R>>>.
"include/CSIndexedSkipList.h", line 207:     Where: While specializing "CS::IndexedSkipList<CS::T, CS::R>".
"include/CSIndexedSkipList.h", line 207:     Where: Specialized in non-template code.
```

The code above is what starts at 207. But it seems that it's complaining about the reverse_iterator. I can't really make sense of it. I don't have direct access to the Sun compiler, so I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Also, I'm only using one template argument in reverse_iterator, but I noticed the SGI documentation saying that there is no default for the second argument T. Everywhere I've looked though, they just use this:

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
```

That's line 65 that the compiler complains about. Do I need to add T as a parameter? I can't figure out the error in question.

BTW, this works on gcc on all platforms I could find. And it works in Borland as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained at [Comparing C++ Standard Libraries libCstd and libstlport](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/cmp_stlport_libCstd.html), the Sun C++ compiler ships with two implementations of a "C++ standard library": libCstd and libstlport. Unfortunately, libCstd is not standards-conforming, but it is the default for backward-compatibility reasons. Among other differences, libCstd's version of the `std::reverse_iterator` template uses more than one template parameter.

You need to instruct the compiler to use libstlport by passing in the compiler option `-library=stlport4`.

See also:

- [Boost doesn't build on solaris when compiled with libCstd - focus on program_options](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3190)
- [Issue 53 - google-sparsehash - Compilation fails on SunOS CC compiler](https://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/issues/detail?id=53)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, `-library=stlport4` is NOT an option for performance-critical multithreaded applications running on Solaris because the version of `STLPort` shipped with Sun Studio 12.1/12.2 is much slower than `libCstd` due to spinlock mutexes on allocation/deallocation that are too slow on Solaris. `STLPort5` should to be better in this regard, but I failed to build it on Solaris. It seems like `STLPort` is no longer actively supported or used on Solaris, to say the least. So, we had to switch to `libCstd` completely for all of our software, both on SPARC and on x86.